# HTML table inside bootstrap accordion looses header relation

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, nvda, wcag2.0

In my angular project, I am having a common table component in it. I have used semantic html table for that table. Issue is that NVDA can announce the table headers in another place, but not inside a bootstrap accordion.

Here is my html code for table:

```
<div class="volume-table">

    <table>
        <caption>Volume Table</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr class="heading-row">
                <td></td>
                <th scope="col" *ngFor="let item of columns">{{ item.name }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="body-row" *ngFor="let item of volumeTableData;let i = index">
                <th scope="row">{{ item.name }}</th>
                <td *ngFor="let element of columns; let j = index">
                    {{ item[element.prop] }}
                </td>
    
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        
    </table>

</div>
```

Had some face similar kind of issue?

Comment: What do you mean "not accessible"?

Comment: By accessible i mean WCAG accessible standards. I have a table with header cells in top row and first column. Suppose if a user is currently in 2nd row and 2nd column, nvda should reads 'Column_Header column 2 Column_Value' but instead it reads only 'column 2 Column_Value'

Comment: Can you specify which standards are not being met in your case?

Comment: A table is a table, regardless of location. Please revise to clarify the problem _in your post_, and tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies, it got solved, i used role="table" along with headers and id

Comment: That’s a weird situation. Good for you to have found a solution, but this should not be necessary, since role=table is already implicit with `<table>` and the same goes for headers. If this solved your issue, something else must have messed with the original roles of the table, which would be the root cause of your issue. Right now, it seems you have fixed some symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I used role="table" along with headers and id in table.

```
<table role="table">
    <caption>Volume Table</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr class="heading-row">
            <th id="name"></th>
            <th *ngFor="let item of columns" [id]="item.prop">{{ item.name }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="body-row" *ngFor="let item of volumeTableData;let i = index">
            <th [id]="'name' + i">{{ item.name }}</th>
            <td *ngFor="let element of columns; let j = index" headers="{{ element.prop }} {{ 'name' + i }}">
                {{ item[element.prop] }}
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```